# Multi-endpoint S/FTP/S solution?

Tags: ftp, sftp

What options are out there for a central FTP (or SFTP or FTPS) server which has endpoints for other servers on the network. E.g. you login to the "central" FTP server and can then transfer files to any server configured as an endpoint. Features would include:

- FXP capability to transfer files between endpoint, on the server (don't bring data local).
- Grouped endpoints or multi-destination transfers. E.g. one large file can be streamed to multiple endpoints at the same time.
- Security, of course (username/password, SSL/TLS).
- Authentication via LDAP.
- Direct transfer to endpoints. E.g. data does not have to flow through the central FTP server - can establish a connection directly with the endpoint (after being auth'd by the central FTP server). Thus eliminating the central FTP server as a bottleneck.
- Web-based access in addition to traditional FTP/SFTP.